# How do you start auto increment at a higher number in Webmatrix?

Tags: razor, sql-server-ce, auto-increment, webmatrix

I am using SQL Sever CE and trying auto increment my table starting at 50000. I see basic SQL code out there but I do not know how to translate for Webmatrix. Do I need to use a different program to interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created your table, use the Query editor to run this:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [Id] IDENTITY (50000,1)
```

You can reach the Query editor via the Database Workspace » Home tab » New Query